# Android list view with adapter displays only the first item (several times)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, listadapter

I created a `ListView` and a custom adapter to use with the list view. For some reason, if I add more than one item to the list, it does show several items, but all of them are identical to the first one.
At first I used a layout file to create each item but then I gave up and dynamically created a text view just to test it. It didn't work in both ways.

[List with same item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBOVx.png)

Here is my code:

**ArtistAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.list2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArtistAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<String> artists;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ArtistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> artists)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.artists = artists;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public ArtistAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this(context, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return artists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return artists.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        if(v == null)
        {
            //LayoutInflater li = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            //v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);
            //((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText((String)getItem(i));
            v = new TextView(context);
            ((TextView)v).setText(getItem(i));
            ((TextView)v).setTextSize(50);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void add(String name)
    {
        artists.add(name);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.list2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView l;
    EditText et;
    Button bt;

    //ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ArtistAdapter aa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        l = findViewById(R.id.list);
        et = findViewById(R.id.input);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.submit);

        bt.setOnClickListener(this);

        //aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item,new ArrayList<String>());

        aa = new ArtistAdapter(this);
        l.setAdapter(aa);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String inp = getInput();
        if(inp.length() == 0) return;
        aa.add(inp);
        //aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        empty();
    }

    private String getInput()
    {
        return et.getText().toString();
    }

    private void empty()
    {
        et.setText("");
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:hint="Something..."
        />
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:text="Submit!"
        />
    
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ArtistAdapter getView first variant is OK, second is wrong.

Comment: @Style-7 what do you mean?

Comment: LayoutInflater li = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); and next 3 lines - ok

Comment: @Style-7 no, as I said, I checked both and both of them aren't working

Comment: Try move `((TextView)v).setText(getItem(i));` to after `if (v == null) {........}`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a custom Adapter? Otherwise this code works well using `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ListView l;
EditText et;
Button bt;

ArrayAdapter<String> artistAdapter;
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = findViewById(R.id.list);
    et = findViewById(R.id.input);
    bt = findViewById(R.id.submit);

    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    artistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item, R.id.textView,listItems);
    l.setAdapter(artistAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String inp = getInput();
    if(inp.length() == 0) return;
    listItems.add(inp);
    artistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    empty();
}

private String getInput()
{
    return et.getText().toString();
}

private void empty()
{
    et.setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I need a custom adapter, I'm only using strings because I want it to work first then I'll add more stuff like pictures....

Comment: @ShaniDahan please check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the arraylist and then set the adapter. For some reason notify adapter is not working. Here's the solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ListView l;
EditText et;
Button bt;


ArtistAdapter artistAdapter;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = findViewById(R.id.list);
    et = findViewById(R.id.input);
    bt = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    artistAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(this, arrayList);
    l.setAdapter(artistAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String inp = getInput();

    if(inp.length() == 0) return;
    arrayList.add(inp);
    l.setAdapter(artistAdapter);

    empty();
}

private String getInput()
{
    return et.getText().toString();
}

private void empty()
{
    et.setText("");
}
```

}

====

```
public class ArtistAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

{
private ArrayList artists;
private Context context;

```
public ArtistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> artists)
{
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.artists = artists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return artists.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int i) {
    return artists.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    if(v == null)
    {
        v = new TextView(context);
        ((TextView)v).setText(getItem(i));
        ((TextView)v).setTextSize(50);
    }
    return v;
}
```

}